# How to use custom filter in Angularjs with fusion chart?

Tags: angularjs, json, fusioncharts

I'm facing an issue in Angularjs with  fusion chart,  I need to  set  the data as per one of the value in json  data. My fusion chart  is showing  the jumbled data.  but i need to  filter  it as per the requirement which  as shown in  the given image.

[image]

But the result i'm  getting is :
[image]

Few data is coming  under **SBHL** which is supposed to  come under the **SBML**
I need to  filter  the data as per the product i.e,(SBHL or SBML).

Let me show you the `script` and the `html` that I'm using for fusion chart.

**index.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid mid-content" ng-show='searchResults'>
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-1" id="outPopUp">
          <div fusioncharts width="700" height="450" type="msstackedcolumn2d" chart="{{attrs}}"
                    categories="{{categories}}"
                    dataset="{{dataset}}">
           </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

**json data**

```
[
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 3005,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 3005
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 4810,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 4810
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 1610,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1610
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 793,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 793
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 1084,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1084
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 1583,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1583
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 473,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 473
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 273,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 273
  }
]
```

**script.js**

```
$scope.categories = [{
    "font": "Arial",
    "fontsize": "15",
    "fontcolor": "000000"

  }];
  $scope.attrs = {
    "palette": "3",
    "numdivlines": '3',
    "numberprefix": "",
    "useRoundEdges": "1",
    "bgcolor": "FFFFFF,FFFFFF",
    "showalternatehgridcolor": "1",
    "showvalues": "0",
    "yaxismaxvalue": "10000",
    "showLegend": "1",
    "showborder": "0",
    "labelDisplay": "wrap",
    "yAxisName": "Number Of Accounts",
    "maxLabelHeight": "1500"
  };


    $scope.dataset = [];
  $scope.generate = function() {
  $scope.searchResults = false
  $scope.showLoader = true
  var data = reportService.allocationCollection($scope.query).success(function(data) {

    var products = [];
    var buckets = [];
    var catObject = [];
    var catCollection = [];
    var item = {};

    var seriesItem = {};
    var catHolder = {};
    var valHolder = {};
    var valCollection = [];
    var allocatedCollection = [];
    var collectedCollection = [];
    var allocatedDataSet = [];
    var collectedDataSet = [];

    var tempDataSet = {};
    var maxYaxisVal = 0;

      $scope.dataset2 = data

      for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {

        if (data[i].allocatedAccount > maxYaxisVal) {
          maxYaxisVal = data[i].allocatedAccount;
        }
        if (data[i].collectedAccount > maxYaxisVal) {
          maxYaxisVal = data[i].collectedAccount;
        }
        if (products.indexOf(data[i].product) == -1) {
          item = {};
          item["label"] = "Allocated\t\tCollected(" + data[i].product +")";
          item["font"] = "Arial";
          item["fontsize"] = "15";

          catObject.push(item);
          products.push(data[i].product);
        }
        if ((i == (data.length - 1))) {
          valHolder = {};
          valHolder["value"] = data[i].allocatedAccount;
          allocatedCollection.push(valHolder);
          valHolder = {};
          valHolder["value"] = data[i].collectedAccount;
          collectedCollection.push(valHolder);
        }
        if ((buckets.indexOf(data[i].bucket) == -1) || (i == (data.length - 1))) {               

          if (buckets.length > 0) {
            seriesItem = {};
            seriesItem["seriesname"] = data[i - 1].bucket + "allocated";
            seriesItem["data"] = allocatedCollection;
            allocatedDataSet.push(seriesItem);

            seriesItem = {};
            seriesItem["seriesname"] = data[i - 1].bucket + "collected";

            seriesItem["data"] = collectedCollection;
            collectedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
            collectedCollection = [];
            allocatedCollection = [];
            console.log(allocatedDataSet)
          }
          buckets.push(data[i].bucket);
          console.log(buckets.length);
        }
        valHolder = {};
        valHolder["value"] = data[i].allocatedAccount;
        allocatedCollection.push(valHolder);
        valHolder = {};
        valHolder["value"] = data[i].collectedAccount;
        collectedCollection.push(valHolder);


      }
      catHolder["category"] = catObject;
      catCollection.push(catHolder);


      tempDataSet["dataset"] = allocatedDataSet;
      dataSet = [];
      dataSet.push(tempDataSet);

      tempDataSet = {};
      tempDataSet["dataset"] = collectedDataSet;
      dataSet.push(tempDataSet);

      $scope.categories = JSON.stringify(catCollection);
      $scope.dataset = JSON.stringify(dataSet);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
      $scope.attrs.yaxismaxvalue = maxYaxisVal;


    $scope.showLoader = false;
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
      }, 'slow');
    }, 200);

    $scope.results = data;


    if ($scope.results.length > 0) {
      console.log($scope.query.product);

      $scope.searchResults = true
        //console.log("hi");
      _.forEach($scope.results.entities, function(obj) {
        console.log("hi");
        obj.isChecked = false;
      });
      console.log("hi1");
      $scope.view_data = $scope.results.slice($scope.skip, $scope.items + $scope.skip);
      //console.log("hi2");
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.results.length;
      console.log(data);

      $scope.results = data;
      //$scope.results = $filter('orderByValue')(data);
      // called on header click





    } else {
      $scope.searchResults = false
      notificationFactory.warning('No results Found')
      $scope.showLoader = false
    }



  }).error(function(data) {
    notificationFactory.warning('Error Searching Reports')
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

Those  who  answer will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The logic was not correctly implemented for Multi-series stacked column chart.
The resultant JSON structure of the code does not comply to the supported format for the said chart hence data was getting wrongly visualized for both the categories. Please visit the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Soumya_dutta/u7ju71oo/29/

Please check the modified html and script

```
<html ng-app="HelloApp">

  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>
         <div fusioncharts width="700" height="450" type="msstackedcolumn2d" dataSource="{{dataSource}}" categories="{{categories}}" chart="{{attrs}}" dataFormat= 'json' dataset="{{dataset}}" events="events">
                          </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.chartoptions = {
    "dataEmptyMessage": "No data to display <br> Do these steps..."
  };
  data =[
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 3005,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 3005
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 4810,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 4810
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 1610,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1610
  },
  {
    "product": "SBHL",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 793,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 793
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": ">90",
    "allocatedAccount": 1084,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1084
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "0-30",
    "allocatedAccount": 1583,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 1583
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "31-60",
    "allocatedAccount": 473,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 473
  },
  {
    "product": "SBML",
    "bucket": "61-90",
    "allocatedAccount": 273,
    "collectedAccount": 0,
    "pendingCollectionOfAccounts": 273
  }
]
$scope.attrs = {
                "palette":"3",
                "numdivlines":'3',
                "numberprefix": "",
                "useRoundEdges":"1",
                "bgcolor": "FFFFFF,FFFFFF",
                "showalternatehgridcolor": "1",
                "showvalues": "0",
                "yaxismaxvalue": "1000",
                "showLegend":"1",
                "showborder": "0",
                "labelDisplay": "wrap", 
                "yAxisName": "Number Of Accounts",
                "maxLabelHeight":"150"
             };
var products = [];
var catObject = [];
    var catCollection = [];
    var item = {};
     var catHolder = {};
      var buckets = [];
      var dataSet=[];
       var seriesItem = {};
       var productWiseAllocationarr=[];
       var productWiseCollectionarr= [];
        var allocatedDataSet = [];
    var collectedDataSet = [];
      var tempDataSet = {};
      var allseries={};
      var collseries={};
      var allocatedData = [];
    var collectedData = [];

     for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (products.indexOf(data[i].product)== -1)
                {
                    item = {};
                    item["label"] = "Allocated\tCollected   " + data[i].product;
                    item["font"] = "Arial";
                    item["fontsize"] = "15";

                    catObject.push(item);
                    products.push(data[i].product);
                    catHolder["category"] =  catObject ;

                }
                 if (buckets.indexOf(data[i].bucket)==-1)
                {

                         buckets.push(data[i].bucket);
                }


     }
     for(var j=0;j<products.length;j++)
     {
     for(var p=0;p<data.length;p++)
     {
     if(data[p].product==products[j])
     {
     var productWiseAllocation = {};
     productWiseAllocation.name=data[p].product;
     productWiseAllocation.series= data[p].bucket;
      productWiseAllocation.amount= data[p].allocatedAccount;
      productWiseAllocationarr.push( productWiseAllocation);
      var productWiseCollection ={};
      productWiseCollection.name=data[p].product;
       productWiseCollection.series=data[p].bucket;
        productWiseCollection.amount=data[p].collectedAccount;
        productWiseCollectionarr.push( productWiseCollection);
     }
     }
     }
     for(var b =0;b<buckets.length;b++)
     {
      allseries = {};
       allseries.name =buckets[b]+"allocated";
       allseries.data=[];
        collseries = {};
       collseries.name =buckets[b]+"collected";
       collseries.data=[];
     for(var pr=0;pr< productWiseAllocationarr.length;pr++)
     {
       if(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {

       allseries.data.push(productWiseAllocationarr[pr].amount);


       }
        if( productWiseCollectionarr[pr].series==buckets[b])
       {

       collseries.data.push(productWiseCollectionarr[pr].amount);


       }
     }
      allocatedData.push(allseries);
       collectedData.push(collseries);
     }
    for(var w=0;w<allocatedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] = allocatedData[w].name;
        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<allocatedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=allocatedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
        allocatedData[w].data;
        allocatedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }

         for(var w=0;w< collectedData.length;w++)
    {
      seriesItem = {};
       seriesItem["seriesname"] =  collectedData[w].name;

        seriesItem["data"]=[];
        for(var g =0;g<collectedData[w].data.length;g++)
        {
        var datavalue={};
        datavalue.value=collectedData[w].data[g];
        seriesItem["data"].push(datavalue);
        }
         collectedDataSet.push(seriesItem);
    }
     tempDataSet["dataset"] = allocatedDataSet;


            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
            tempDataSet = {};
            tempDataSet["dataset"] = collectedDataSet;
            dataSet.push(tempDataSet);
   catCollection.push(catHolder);

      $scope.categories  = JSON.stringify(catCollection);
      $scope.dataset = JSON.stringify(dataSet);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
        });
```